# Can a bipedal (chained) eidolon pass itself off as a human or similar race?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, eidolon

So I saw the bodyguard suggested build in the SRD and thought "That sounds awesome, but you know what will make it even better? If it were a shinobi." Yes, I know very anime that's just how I am. The rune is an obvious problem but giving them a fox mask would build on the anime field and hide the rune as per the rules (see below). Can a bipedal take on a human form or does it have to be a monstrous humanoid or something similar. Maybe an Aasimar or a Humanoid Fey? If not is there a way to accomplish this with feats or archetypes.

The SRD says

> The eidolon’s physical appearance is up to the summoner, but it always
>   appears as some sort of fantastical creature. This control is not fine
>   enough to make the eidolon appear like a specific creature. The
>   eidolon also bears a glowing rune that is identical to a rune that
>   appears on the summoner’s forehead as long as the eidolon is summoned.
>   While this rune can be hidden through mundane means, it cannot be
>   concealed through magic that changes appearance, such as alter self or
>   polymorph (although invisibility does conceal it as long as the spell
>   lasts).

> Biped Starting Statistics
>
> Size Medium; Speed 30 ft.; AC +2 natural armor; Saves Fort (good), Ref
>   (bad), Will (good); Attack 2 claws (1d4); Ability Scores Str 16, Dex
>   12, Con 13, Int 7, Wis 10, Cha 11
>
> Free Evolutions
>
> Claws, limbs (arms), limbs (legs).

> Bodyguard Source: PZO1117
>
> The eidolon looks like a humanoid warrior. The natural armor of a
>   Bodyguard eidolon appears to be a suit of metal plate, though this
>   armor is actually part of the eidolon’s body. Bodyguard eidolons are
>   normally trained in a variety of dangerous weapons.
>
> 11 points: Base Form biped; Primary Evolutions improved natural armor,
>   weapon training; Secondary Evolutions ability increase (Strength),
>   fast healing, weapon training (martial).

An unchained Eidolon can do that via the Acesstor Subtype and many others which is why I specified chained which from what I've heard is a massive upgrade from unchained.

> Ancestor source: PZO9473 Whether created by bonding with the soul of a
>   petitioner that was the summoner’s ancestor in life or calling upon
>   the impressions of such a soul left behind on the Ethereal Plane or
>   the Akashic Record, ancestor eidolons are outsiders cast in the mold
>   of mortals, and exhibit extraordinary skill and talent. They usually
>   appear as idealized versions of the bodies they possessed while still
>   alive, but distinctive and proud. Ancestor eidolons lend whatever aid
>   they can to their summoner, who typically has some form of familial
>   connection with the eidolon, be it by blood, honor, or devotion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

Like any creature, an eidolon can pretend to be something it is not.  What you are describing sounds like the version of that which is called a [disguise check](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/disguise/).

Your eidolon would roll its disguise skill and the check total would be used (with various modifiers) against the Perception checks of everybody who might suspect something is up or is otherwise entitled to a check to see through the disguise.  Being bipedal and generally human-shaped and sized should help a lot with the modifiers to the disguise roll.

If your eidolon is bad at disguises, you [may](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2n4kq?Disguise-skill-used-on-others) be able to use the Disguise skill on its behalf, or have someone else in the party do that.  It is not, however, clear whether or not you can do that and so the efficacy of attempts to do so and beliefs as to what the rules on the matter are will vary greatly by table.

Comment: Yeah, *Just have the creature wear a mundane disguise* is what I was thinking, too. However, it may be useful to mention that the Disguise skill can be used on others so that the eidolon needn't put on its own makeup or Groucho glasses.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Can it?  I thought that was a table-by-table thing with no clear rules. I'll put in a note, and make it stronger if you can get me a source.

Comment: I guess it *might be* table-by-table and I've just never been at a table where Disguise on others was disallowed? An *inability* to use the Disguise skill on others would strike me as deeply strange and lacking in verisimilitude. Maybe pose a question?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Question [posed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/161906/can-you-use-disguise-on-others-in-pathfinder). If you think the framing is bad, feel free to change it; I'm not sure the angle I put in it is the right angle to ask the question from.

Comment: I don't know if the rules-as-written need be emphasized quite that much (good answers will either find rules or they won't), but it should work. Good luck.