# How close can a bipedal (chained) eidolon get to a human-like appearance?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, eidolon

So I asked a similar question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/161878/can-a-bipedal-chained-eidolon-pass-itself-off-as-a-human-or-similar-race) and that was confirmed. So I want to extend it. Since an eidolon can get close enough to a human pass a disguise check to pretend to be one, just how close can it get? Looking like it's made of clay or porcelain could be called roughly human but anyone who takes a long hard look is going to tell the difference unless it's wearing full body armor or something similar.

The rules for the eidolon's appearance read as follows.

> The eidolon’s physical appearance is up to the summoner, but it always
>   appears as some sort of fantastical creature. This control is not fine
>   enough to make the eidolon appear like a specific creature. The
>   eidolon also bears a glowing rune that is identical to a rune that
>   appears on the summoner’s forehead as long as the eidolon is summoned.
>   While this rune can be hidden through mundane means, it cannot be
>   concealed through magic that changes appearance, such as alter self or
>   polymorph (although invisibility does conceal it as long as the spell
>   lasts).

> Biped Starting Statistics
>
> Size Medium; Speed 30 ft.; AC +2 natural armor; Saves Fort (good), Ref
>   (bad), Will (good); Attack 2 claws (1d4); Ability Scores Str 16, Dex
>   12, Con 13, Int 7, Wis 10, Cha 11
>
> Free Evolutions
>
> Claws, limbs (arms), limbs (legs).

> Bodyguard Source: PZO1117
>
> The eidolon looks like a humanoid warrior. The natural armor of a
>   Bodyguard eidolon appears to be a suit of metal plate, though this
>   armor is actually part of the eidolon’s body. Bodyguard eidolons are
>   normally trained in a variety of dangerous weapons.
>
> 11 points: Base Form biped; Primary Evolutions improved natural armor,
>   weapon training; Secondary Evolutions ability increase (Strength),
>   fast healing, weapon training (martial).

An unchained Eidolon can do that via a few subtypes ancestor and angel being prime examples which is why I specified chained which from what I've heard is a massive upgrade from unchained.

> Ancestor source: PZO9473 Whether created by bonding with the soul of a
>   petitioner that was the summoner’s ancestor in life or calling upon
>   the impressions of such a soul left behind on the Ethereal Plane or
>   the Akashic Record, ancestor eidolons are outsiders cast in the mold
>   of mortals, and exhibit extraordinary skill and talent. They usually
>   appear as idealized versions of the bodies they possessed while still
>   alive, but distinctive and proud. Ancestor eidolons lend whatever aid
>   they can to their summoner, who typically has some form of familial
>   connection with the eidolon, be it by blood, honor, or devotion.

> Angel Hailing from the higher planes, angel eidolons are creatures of
>   exquisite beauty. They usually appear in idealized humanoid forms,
>   with smooth skin, shining hair, and bright eyes. Angel eidolons are
>   impeccably honorable, trustworthy, and diplomatic, but they do not shy
>   away from confrontation when facing off against evil and its minions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With use of the Disguise skill, the Eidolon can appear to be fully human.

Or elven or dwarven or whatever you want.

For the most part, as long as it's vaguely humanoid in base form and appearance, it can attempt to pass for a human. How convincing it is is another matter entirely. Lets take a look at the disguise modifier table for reference.

- Minor details only: +5
- Different Gender: -2
- Different Race: -2
- Different age: -2/step
- Different size: -10/step

We can assume your Eidolon is medium, and attempting to disguise itself as a medium humanoid (rather than say, a giant or halfling), so no penalty there, and we can assume that they aren't trying to appear as a different gender, so no penalty there either. Being ageless, most outsides default to adult age appearance, so unless you have a reason to want it to look excpetionally old (like the venerable age category and a -6 penalty), there won't be a penalty there either. That leaves us with race, which only imposes a -2 penalty. Depending upon your Charisma modifier and any investure of skill ranks and/or feats in the Disguise skill, you can easily produce a convincing disguise.

Alternatively, since you and your Eidolon can share spells, even those that would not normally effect a creature of its type, you can cast *Alter Self* on it to *actually* turn it into a humanoid of some type, albeit temporarily, or you could pick up a wand/scroll of *Disguise Self* for a nice +10 bonus that will last far longer.

There's also the option to pick up a *Hat of Disguise* for a paltry 1,800 GP.

On an related note, good luck getting your DM to allow the standard (chained) Summoner. There's a reason the the Unchained Summoner was nerfed, and it's generally seen as a reasonably balanced class now.